# Custom HTTP status Code (in 900 Series) on RestController Advice

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-restcontroller

My application is supposed to return a custom HTTP status code when there is a business exception.

I'm trying to implement the HTTP status as 999 in case of a business exception but could not find a way to implement it in rest controller advice.

I want to return HTTP status 999 in case of a business exception. Please guide me on how to implement it.

```
@Import({ ErrorCodeUtil.class })
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @Autowired
private ErrorCodeUtil errorCodeUtil;
@ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(// Return 999 here)
@ResponseBody
public ErrorResult handleException(BusinessException e) {
    String msg = e.getMessage();
    log.error(msg, e);
    return new ErrorResult(e.getErrorCode(), msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard, there are only five classes of Http Status code from 1xx to 5xx. Check this [link](https://httpstatuses.com/).

What you can do is in your controller advice, define the return type with status code property.

For example:

```
ErrorResult errorResult = new ErrorResult();
errorResult.setStatusCode(900);
errorResult.setMessage(e.getMessage());
```

You can use     `@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY)`
instead. Now, the method looks like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BusinessException.class)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY)
@ResponseBody 
public ErrorResult handleException(BusinessException e) {
ErrorResult errorResult = new ErrorResult();
errorResult.setStatusCode(e.getStatusCode()); //set status code 900 when throwing exception or use errorResult.setStatusCode(900);
errorResult.setMessage(e.getMessage());
}
```